# Setting column in pandas dataframe in iterrows returns KeyError

Tags: python, pandas

I'm brand new to pandas and am having difficulty doing, what I assume, is a fairly straightforward task.

I have a dataframe with schema

```
price   address createdAt   conversionTime  json
```

I then want to use the value in the `json` column, make a POST request, and make a new entry in the dataframe `state` which is based on the response.

I have:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    raw_json = post_request(eval(row["json"]))
    df["state"][index] = raw_json['d']['sStateAbbr']
```

But, when I run this I get `KeyError: 'state'`

How would one do this?

Also, I'm sure there's a simpler way using `apply()` but I couldn't get that to evaluate the string as json. Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`df["state"] = df.apply(lambda row: post_request(eval(row.json)['d']['sStateAbbr'], axis=1)`

I think this should do it. Please do tell if you get any errors since I can't exactly test run this on my end.